# Change Elasticsearch Path Hierarchy Tokenizer delimiter

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer

I'm having some issues with the Path Hierarchy Tokenizer.
What I need is to use the path hierarchy tokenizer using backslash as delimiter.

What I'm trying to do is to index and search Windows paths.

```
 "index": {
  "analysis": {
     "tokenizer": {
        "path": {
           "type": "path_hierarchy",
           "delimeter": "\\"
        }
     },
     "analyzer": {
        "analyzer_path": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "path",
           "filter": "lowercase"
        }
     }
  }
```

When I try to get the tokenized elements of a custom string, I get a single token

```
GET /test/_analyze?analyzer=analyzer_path&text=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\hello.exe


"tokens": [
  {
     "token": "c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\hello.exe",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 43,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 1
  }
]
```

Using a forward slash gives the correct result

```
GET /test/_analyze?analyzer=analyzer_path&text=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/hello.exe
```

and I got all the tokens.

It seems that the delimiter setting is completely ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, `delimeter` should read [`delimiter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html). That's probably the issue.

The reason it works with forward slashes is because the forward slash is the default delimiter in case none is specified and since `delimeter` is wrongly spelled, the default delimiter is used instead.

What they should probably do is issue an error because of an unknown parameter, but instead they [just silently ignore it](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/148265bd164cd5a614cd020fb480d5974f523d81/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory.java). You could probably [file an issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/new).

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.